# Adapter problem with getTag() ,return null

Tags: android, tags, scroll, nullpointerexception

this is my header

```
public class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter implements OnScrollListener {
```

in my adapter I set the tag like this

```
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                final View view = super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
                final MyCache cache = new MyCache();
            view.setTag(cache); 
            }
```

than I have some method

```
public void metA(){
//here I want to read the tag
//how can I do that ?
}
```

I also impplement scroll listenter

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
//how to read for example the third item in the list ?
//item.getTag() returns null
}
```

I tried with getItem(0) but I also receive null pointer exceptions...
What is the right way to read the tags in the onScroll method, what the view actually contains ?
I know I do something very stupid but I can't figured out.

Comment: Can I see the whole source of your adapter?

Comment: it is too large, but the adapter it self is not the problem. My question is how to take the tag (getTag()) of the view that I set wit setTag() in newView method. My problem is how to read the tags ?

Answer (score 0):

For the `getTag()` method you should try to remove the `final` keyword from you `View` declaration, this may be the problem (I'm not 100% sure). Also I'm not sure whay yoru `MyCache()` class is doing and why you need to set a `MyCache` object on each `View`. Maybe it would be a better solution to just add one `MyCache` instance, as an adapter class variable.

And for the `getItem()` method be sure that you have implemented properly this method, and that you return an item from your list of objects.

To get the tag from a `View` you just need to use :

```
   (MyCache)view.getTag();
```

**Edit:** to get the `View tag` in your `getView()` method, just use the parameter `convertView` of the `getView()` method:

```
       public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
            if(convertView!=null)
                 (MyCache)convertView.getTag();
            // code....
       }
```

Comment: I know :). the point is I do not have view it is not the same view as the view in the getview method. "public void metA()" how to get the tag in this mnethod ? that is the problem not getting the tag in getview. Sorry maybe I didn;t explain good when I ask the question...